# larastan ignore model scope function warnings

Tags: laravel-10

```
Laravel version - 10
Larastan - 2
```

I have model called Template and in that model I have added scope function Active.

```
public function scopeActive($query): Builder
{
   return $query->where('is_active', 1);
}
```

In one of my class I call the above scope as

```
$this->templateRepository
       ->getModel()
       ->select('template_title', 'id')
       ->active()
```

When I analyse the code using Larastan it showing following error.

```
 47     Call to an undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder<Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model>::active().
```

I have followed instructions in [link](https://github.com/larastan/larastan/issues/925) and [this link](https://github.com/larastan/larastan/commit/88422fb90e85385245fb1badcaf5fbd8e0a1530d) and added @method tag in Model Template.php as following

```
/**
 * @method Builder<static> active(Builder $builder)
 */
class Template extends Model
{
```

But the larastan is still showing above mentioned error